# Got unexpected results while creating rock, paper and scissor game

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random

I am creating a rock, paper and scissors game.

```
 rock = '''
    _______
---'   ____)
      (_____)
      (_____)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

paper = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
          _______)
         _______)
---.__________)
'''

scissors = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
       __________)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

#Write your code below this
import random
list = [rock, paper, scissors]
choice = int(input("What do you choose? Type 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper or 2 for Scissors.\n"))

my_choice = list[choice]
print (my_choice)

computer_choice = list[random.randint(0,2)]
print("Computer chose:")
print(computer_choice)
if my_choice == computer_choice:
  print('its a draw')
elif my_choice == 0 and computer_choice == 2 :
    print("You won")
elif my_choice == 1 and computer_choice == 0 :
  print ("You won")
elif my_choice == 2 and computer_choice == 1 :
  print ("You won")
else :
  print ("You lose")
```

I don't know what's wrong with this, but I am not able to get winner. All my results are "You lose",
though I included all my winning possibilities.

Comment: @Avijeet: No, it is an element of `list`, which (in this code) is a list of strings.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks for pointing it out, I got confused due to the `list` being inbuilt

Comment: @ScottHunter His point is right though, the computer choice is not a number

Comment: Did you test any Draw possibilities?

Comment: Great I corrected my mistake and it worked out perfectly. Thanks @ScottHunter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`computer_choice` is an element of `list` (which is a *terrible* name, btw), and thus will never be equal to any number.

Comment: ... and `list` is a list of strings, so `computer_choice` is a string.

Comment: @khelwood: Kind of hoped the author could figure that out.

Comment: Without that it sounds like you're saying that an element of a list can never be equal to a number.